# Facebook AS3 api - mobile login window missing cancel button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, mobile, air

I am using [this](https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/), somewhat outdated, library.
When i log in a webview loads the following url

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456789&display=touch&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&scope=publish_actions,user_friends

I get a working login page, but there is no cancel button. Am I using the wrong address, or is this something the library would be responsible for adding?

Regards,
Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use this library. It is not maintained any more, and wasn't updated since oct. 2011 ... It is broken.
I use the Facebook API in AIR using HTMLLoaders and URLLoaders. All the flow is documented on the facebook developper's pages. But it's not that easy.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. That i probably a better idea than using an outdated library. Are you familiar with this library:

https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook

Last commit in February, think I might give it a go before doing it from scratch.